# ImportError: cannot import name 'remote_connection' from 'selenium.webdriver.chrome'

Tags: python, selenium, bots

When trying to import this library

```
from instaclient import InstaClient
```

I get the following error

```
C:\Users\localhost\Desktop\Bot>python bot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 11, in <module>
    from instaclient import InstaClient
  File "C:\Users\localhost\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\instaclient\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from instaclient.client.instaclient import InstaClient
  File "C:\Users\localhost\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\instaclient\client\instaclient.py", line 28, in <module>
    from instaclient.client.scraper import Scraper
  File "C:\Users\localhost\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\instaclient\client\scraper.py", line 26, in <module>
    from instaclient.client.component import Component
  File "C:\Users\localhost\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\instaclient\client\component.py", line 20, in <module>
    from instaclient.client.driver import HiddenChromeWebDriver
  File "C:\Users\localhost\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\instaclient\client\driver.py", line 12, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome import service, webdriver, remote_connection
ImportError: cannot import name 'remote_connection' from 'selenium.webdriver.chrome' (C:\Users\localhost\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\__init__.py)
```

Environment:

```
Python 3.7.8
Selenium 4.1
InstaClient 2.9
```

https://pypi.org/project/instaclient/#description

Answer (score -1):

Importing InstaClient is not the issue, it is with the selenium imports

You cannot import webdriver and remote using `from selenium.webdriver.chrome import service, webdriver, remote_connection` as detailed in the following exception:

> `ImportError: cannot import name 'remote_connection' from 'selenium.webdriver.chrome' (C:\Users\localhost\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\__init__.py)`

You need to import **webdriver** separately

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

You require **service** only if you are using a locally installed driver for selenium automation using a browser on your local machine, for example

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
service = ChromeService(executable_path'/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
```

If you require selenium automation using a **remote** server hosting browsers like selenium grid, see following example

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor="<server_address>",
    options=options
)
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
driver.quit()
```

Where <server_address> would be something like `http://192.168.1.100:4444/wd/hub`